# Germany Blue Card after 2 years - can I change to a job not related to my degree?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I've been on a Blue Card in Berlin for over 2 years (current position matches my uni degree). Now I'm interested in getting a job in a new field which is not relevant to my degree (job - IT, degree - economics). The salary is well above the limits. I used to work in IT in the past and my economics knowledge will be helpful for this kind of position, but the focus will clearly be on software development.

It's not clear for me how the 2 year rule for Blue Card holders (can change jobs after 2 years without extra approval) works in this case and what will be the implications.

1. Should I inform the immigration authorities?
2. Can I be forced to switch from a Blue Card to another type of visa by them since my job will no longer match my degree?

Comment: I don't think the degree needs to match the position, even for the first application / first two years. What makes you think that?

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/2b4h7m4w

Q: Which requirements need to be fulfilled in order for an EU Blue Card to be issued?
A: ...Furthermore, the employment must be commensurate with the qualification.

AFAIK, currently "qualification" in Germany is only higher education qualification, years of experience can't substitute it.

When I was applying for blue card in my home country they were not sure that my degree matched the job fully and were even checking the courses I took at the university and courses' credits.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, years of experience cannot substitute for a lack of degree and Germany is especially fastitidious with the academic qualifications they recognise. The salary threshold is also far from insignificant. On the other hand, “commensurate” means a qualified job, something that requires a higher education degree but *not* a specific field. I found a document spelling it out and will post an answer.

Comment: Reading it more carefully, at least some partial relevance seems to be required. For reference, I am referring to https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/downloads/DE/veroeffentlichungen/themen/migration/anwendungshinweise-fachkraefteeinwanderungsgesetz.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=3 pp. 76-77.

Comment: I can't really understand one thing. Blue card holder doesn't have to ask permission to change jobs after 2 years on blue card and also blue card holder doesn't have the legal power to make judgment on whether the job matches their degree - these two facts combined make me think that you are free to take any job after 2 years on blue card, since there is no control mechanism in place. But at the same it may lead to blue card holders working on irrelevant jobs (and potentially paid under the threshold), which contradicts the very idea of blue card.

Comment: You have to distinguish the rule and its enforcement. Speed is limited on the whole road network (or most of it, in Germany), not merely on the sections that have a speed camera. If found out, you cannot avoid a fine by claiming you thought the limit wasn't enforced. Broad areas of the law work that way, e.g. tax law. You do not need and couldn't get a ruling regarding every aspect of your taxes, the onus is on you to correctly apply the rules to your situation and file your taxes accordingly.

Comment: Regarding wor permit, some restrictions might not be enforced actively but it's easy to see how they could be: the authorities could review submissions by employers or just perform random spot checks and strip people who didn't follow the rules of their permit. Here again, the onus is on you to apply the rules to your situation. For the salary threshold it's easy: There is little judgment involved and both you and the employer are supposed to know the rules.

Comment: For the link between the field you obtained your degree and the nature of your job, I can see why you would want additional legal security through a formal approval process but it's not fundamentally different, you are still supposed to know the rules and exercise your own judgment. Note that other countries implemented the Blue Card system differently relying on the diploma requirement and salary threshold to filter applicants without the need to look beyond that (hence my initial comment). This more practical approach might reflect slightly different legal cultures.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but I'm still a little confused... So after two years on blue card one does not get any additional freedom? It's just that the judgement whether the new job is compliant with the blue card rules gets passed on from the authorities to the card holder? It just doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: I am not 100% positive, that's why I didn't post an answer. What's clear: Yes there are still restrictions, in particular the salary threshold still applies. Even then, not requiring prior permission to change jobs is a significant additional freedom in and of itself. Also note that after 21 or 33 months (depending on whether or not you speak German), you can apply for a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*. Once you get that, you are not bound by the Blue Card restrictions anymore. 21 months is really short compared to most other situations and makes the two-year rule a bit moot.

Comment: Thank you for all your input. Much appreciated, even though no direct answer given.